# Accessing Struts model's date object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, date, struts2

I have Struts model with date object I want to access it in javascript. I am doing it with hidden field method but on javascript it is giving me invalid date

in JSP I am writing

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenId" value="${model.createdAt.time}"/>
```

in JS

```
$('#someId').html(getTimeDiff( new Date($('#hiddenId').val())));
```

and it it is giving me invalid date

Comment: `in jsp i am writing` did you forgot to add the code of jsp section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a javascript variable to hold a value formatted on the server side.

```
var date = '<s:date name="model.createdAt" format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"/>';
```

You can adjust the format to suit the `Date` constructor.

Comment: ya that i can do but i have to show that in format like 5 Hrs ago as it is shown in social netwirking sites

Comment: You can subtract hours on the server side before you return a result.

Comment: i dont have server side access we are only handled by jsp,s

Comment: jsp,s are running on the server side.

Comment: ya i know.... the java code is with oher team and we dont have access to the ... bieng a s/w engg u would have inderstood that

Comment: you don't need a java code, but you should have access to the jsp.

Answer (score 0):

What is giving invalid date. Is it

- inside `$('#someId').html()`
- `new Date($('#hiddenId').val())`

Correct me if i am wrong but i think `getTimeDiff()` should take in two dates to calculate the difference? Or does it have a global/common date to take difference from

Also what format is `${model.createdAt.time}` returning?
To create a new javascript date the format should be one of the following

- `new Date(milliseconds)`
- `new Date(dateString)`
- `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`

Comment: createdAt date is a java date obj in which ${model.createdAt} returns date string and${model.createdAt.time} returns timestamp and yes you are right second date obj is global variable of current date

Comment: createdAt is a java date obj ${model.createdAt.time} will return date string and ${model.createdAt} will return time stamp and yes second date is a global date variable of current date,

Comment: cool<br/>
However could you answer the other parts of the question<br/>
What is giving invalid date?<br/>
IN what format is ${model.createdAt.time} returning?